# I am unable click on datatables row to send data to text field in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, laravel-5.4

I have a web app in **Laravel 5.4**. In some modules, I have a main form from which datatables are called in a modal dialog window (for example: **if I click on a search button, the modal window appears with the datatables in it**).
***What I am trying to achieve is that when I click on the data in the datatables it closes the modal window and get the clicked info and display it in a specified field in a form, the main form.
But after I put all the necessary scripts, nothing happens when I click on the data in the datatable.***

1. a. **HTML Table**

   ```
                 <section class="panel">
                     <div class="table-responsive">
                       <table width="100%" id="pere-table" class="table" >
                         <thead>
                           <tr>
                             <th>NNID</th>
                             <th>Nom</th>
                             <th>Post-Nom</th>
                             <th>Prenom</th>
                           </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                           <tr >
                             <td class="NNID"></td>
                             <td class="nom"></td>
                             <td class="postnom"></td>
                             <td class="prenom"></td>
                           </tr>
                         </tbody>
                       </table>
                     </div>
             </section>
             <a href="#ajout_pere" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Ajouter</small></a>
   ```

   b.Input Field to receive Data has **pere_nouv** as its id
2. **Controller fetching the data**

   ```
    public function recherchePere ()
       {
        $pere = Pere::join('t_individus','t_adultes.nnid', '=', 
        't_individus.nnid')
        ->select(['t_individus.nom', 't_individus.postnom', 
        't_individus.prenom', 't_individus.nnid'])
        ->where('t_individus.sexe','=','0');

        return Datatables::eloquent($pere)->make(true);

        }
   ```
3. **the ajax for the datatable**

   ```
                  @push('scripts')

                         <script type="text/javascript">
                             $(function() {
                                 $('#pere-table').DataTable({
                                 processing: false,
                                 serverSide: true,
                                 ordering: false,
                                 ajax:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/nouveau_ne/data_peres',
                                 columns :[
                                     {data : 'nnid', name:'t_individus.nnid'},
                                     {data : 'nom', name:'t_individus.nom'},
                                     {data : 'postnom', name:'t_individus.postnom'},
                                     {data : 'prenom', name:'t_individus.prenom'},
                                   ]
                                 });
                               });
                         </script>
                         @endpush
   ```
4. **The route**

   ```
     Route::get('/nouveau_ne/data_peres', ['as' => 'nouveau_ne','uses' => 
     'AdulteController@recherchePere']);
     Route::get('/nouveau_ne/pere', [ 'uses' => 'AdulteController@index']);
   ```
5. **The Jquery Script for Clicking on a row to feed a text box**

   ```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var vpWidth = $(window).width();
     var vpHeight = $(window).height();

     var textClickedOn;
     var pereNouv = $("#pere_nouv");
     var nnid = $(".NNID");
     nnid.click(function(){
     //Get text clicked on
     textClickedOn = $(this).text();
     //alert(textClickedOn);
     pereNouv.val(textClickedOn);
     });
     </script>
   ```

**QUESTION: What am I doing wrong? Your help and tips will be highly appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Click event is attachted to existing elements on page load. The key word here is **existing**. When we load something with ajax we manipulate DOM. We are placing totally new element.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time

try something like :

```
$('body').on('click', '#pere_nouv', function (event) {
    // your code goes here
});
```

or this :

```
$(document).on('click','body #pere_nouv',function(){
    // additional code
});
```

Comment: Thanks @yoeunes for the feedback. The JQuery codes are good. Thanks again. However they didnt work.I figured I had to define the functions inside the datatable like this: 
`$('#mere-table').DataTable().on('click','.NNID_mere',function(){`
`alert('ok'+$('.NNID_mere').text());`
`});` 
I also set the `className` within the same dataTable column I wanted to capture:
`{data : 'nnid', name:'t_individus.nnid', className:"NNID_mere"},`. The only problem is that I am getting all the `.NNID` from all the rows. All I want is to get data from **one cell**... Any idea on how to achieve this?